When is simulated annealing useful?
My experiments with small-scale classic and more real-world problems  (think capacitated vehicle routing with about 50 destinations) suggest that even opensource linear/quadratic programming solvers are quite efficient.
I compare them against methods such as simulated annealing, when all constraints are represented as penalty terms. In my limited experience, SA is always much slower, gives worse and often infeasible solutions. The difference is so stark that I doubt that changing the algorithm details, tuning  hyperparameters, or trying different software implementations will do much.
Also, I failed to find any definite guidance in the literature on what type of problems SA is good for.
So, is SA relevant for operations research at all? What specific problems? Any pointers or references are appreciated!

You basically gave a hint yourself: when exact / more complex methods won't scale anymore. The popular routing-solver of ortools for example has a metaheuristic layer (other components: local-search, dynamic-programming, lp-relaxations, enumeration, constraint-propagators) and one of the implementations is exactly Simulated Annealing.

@sascha great, thanks! But I guess exact methods have counterparts that work as heuristics for large problems? Are there any good refs exploring SA (or similar) vs, say, LP? How big should the problem be? Will SA find any feasible solutions at all at this scale. Sorry, my small-scale experiments made the impression that SA is a scam:) will be happy to to be proven wrong.

You're saying "your small-scale experiment". As sacha mentioned these metaheuristics like SA come to your rescue when exact methods don't scale. Try it yourself. Increase the size of your MIP problem. If you're solving the capacitated VRP using the two-index flow formulation, rather than 50 destinations, go with 500 and see how long you need to wait for the model to finish.

@EhsanK I understand that there is a point beyond which exact solvers just won't work. However, I believe that are many other heuristics that work more directly with, say, the MIP formulation. Such as continuous relaxations, early stopping of branch and bound, column generation etc. I'm looking for any practical guidance for when and why SA can outperform more specialized algorithms.
